# Alert funciona e sweetalert não

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

Estou tentando utilizar `sweetalert` para dar um alerta de "Submitted".

```php
if($rstSql["cod_erro"] == 0)
{
    echo '<script> swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success"); <script>';
}
else
{
   echo '<script>alert("message2");</script>';   
}
```

Aparentemente o alerta padrão funciona, enquanto o SWAL não. 
Testei em outra página e chamada normalmente, as bibliotecas estão sendo chamadas em:

```html
<script src="swap/sweet-alert.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="swap/sweet-alert.css">
```

Quando uso debug no chrome tenho a seguinte mensagem:

> *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property "prototype'of undefined>*

Comment: Qual linha @Felipe que está este erro (no console fala a linha). Poderia postar um exemplo do problema no jsfiddle?

Comment: No código, o erro aparece apenas na linha que chamo o swal, que já postei acima. Porém, obtenho erro em algumas linhas da biblioteca do SweetAlert: _Uncaught TypeError? Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null_.
O engraçado é que utilizo a mesma biblioteca em um arquivo limpo e este funciona.

Comment: Você colocou `<script src="swap/sweet-alert.js"></script> ` dentro de `<head>` e `if($rstSql["cod_erro"] == 0)
{
    echo '<script> swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success"); <script>';
}
else
{
   echo '<script>alert("message2");</script>';   
}` dentro de `<body>`???

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde! Entrei no site do SweetAlert (http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/), abri o console do navegador e digitei a mesma linha que você comentou aí em cima, ou seja:

```
swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
```

Fiz isso pra saber se não era erro de algum parâmetro que você tinha passado ou algo do tipo, mas funcionou corretamente! Então aparentemente o JavaScript do SweetAlert está ok!

Voltei a ler seu post, e percebi que você dá um echo, porém você não está fechando a tag `<script>`.

Por favor, tente substituir essa linha:

```
echo '<script> swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success"); <script>';
```

Por essa:

```
echo '<script> swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success"); </script>';
```

E por favor, nos dê a resposta se funcionou.

Comment: Fiz a alteração e não obtive nenhum resultado.

Comment: Continua aparecendo o mesmo erro no console do chrome?

Comment: Sim, o mesmo erro. Eu acredito que possa estar havendo algum problema com o layout que eu estou usando, que já peguei pronto com diversas bibliotecas. Penso isso porque uma vez que faço isso sem o layout, o alert funciona normalmente.

Comment: Vamos tentar algo? Altera a sua tag <script> onde você chama o JavaScript do SweetAlert para esta: <script type="text/javascript" src="swap/sweet-alert.js"></script>. E por favor, me informe se funcionou.

Comment: Nikofoxxx, não funcionou porque eu uso notepad++ e ele reconhece <script> como javascript por definição.